# Compact integral operator

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

I have this exercise and I don't know how to solve the last question.

> In the following $a,b$ are two real numbers such that $a<b$
>   ,$E=C([a,b],\mathbb{R})$ with the norm $||.||_0$ given by $||.||_0= \sup \lbrace |u(x)|,x\in [a,b] \rbrace)$ and
>
> $E^1=C^1([a,b],\mathbb{R})$ with the norm $||.||_1$
>   ($||u||_1=||u||_0+||u'||_0$ for $u\in E^1$).
>
> 1- Calculate the Green function associated to the problem
>   $-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ and the Dirichlet boundary conditions
>   $u(a)=u(b)=0$  (ok!)
>
> 2-Determinate eigenvalues ​​and eigenfunctions associated to the 
>   problem : $-u''(x)=\lambda u(x) , u(a)=u(b)=0 , x\in (a,b)$ (ok!).
>
> 3- Let $L\colon E\rightarrow E^1$ be the operator defined by :
>
> $$Lu(x)=\int_a^b G(x,t) u(t)dt.$$
>
> Prove that $L$ is compact . $L$ is continuous from $E$ to $C^2\cap H^1_0$.

Can someone help me to solve the question 3 ?

Please help me

thank you .

Comment: Arzelà–Ascoli implies that a function continuous into $C^2$ is automatically compact into $C^1$.

Comment: But how to write ? to prove that $L$ is compact i must prove that $L$ sends the complete space in a relatively compact, so what are the things i must prove ? please help me

Comment: A bounded set in $C^2$ is relatively compact in $C^1$, directly by Arzelà–Ascoli.

Comment: It would probably be easier to help if you said what $G$ you got.

Comment: $G(t,s)= \frac{(a-t)(b-s)}{a-b}$ if $a\leq t\leq s \leq b$ and $\frac{(a-s)(b-t)}{a-b}$ if $a\leq s\leq t \leq b$

Comment: can you give the steps of the prove please ?

Comment: Imust prove that $LE$ is bounded and equicontinuous ?

Comment: If you show that a linear function from some Banach space $X$ to $C^2$ is continuous (equivalently, bounded), then it is compact as a function into $C^1$: the image of a ball in $X$ is bounded in $C^2$, and bounded sets in $C^2$ are immediately bounded in $C^1$ and are equicontinuous along with their derivatives. The inclusion map $C^2\to C^1$ is compact. I'm not sure what to explain...

Comment: i still don't understand what i must prove help me please

Comment: All I've said is that $L$ is compact follows easily from that it is continuous into $C^2$. You still need to prove the latter.

Comment: i must prove that L is bounded ?

Comment: @tomasz please ,.

Comment: You must prove that it is continuous into $C^2\cap H^1_0$. It's linear, so continuous and bounded are the same thing.

Comment: and for the compacteness of L ?

Comment: I have already told you and explained that it follows automatically...

Comment: why we need the continuity on $H^1_0$ ,please ?

Comment: Because that's in the statement of the problem. You don't need it for compactness into $C^1$.

Comment: i could not prove that $L$ is continuous into $C^2\cap H^1_0$, have you an idea ?

Comment: Calculate the derivatives directly, and then the norms to show that it's bounded.

Comment: i derive on x or on t?